# Sort images (using json) to folders with python

Tags: python, json, image, sorting

I've got a large set of images(in one folder) and I've labeled them using software. The output is a json file which contains the labels. I want to write a script that should be able to create folders and move the images according to the description label on the json file. So far I've got python to access json file and display the required label.

CODE1 :

```
import json
import os
with open('filedirectory.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
for i, r in enumerate(data):
     if r['label'] != 'tag' 
            print(i)
            print(r['label']['tag1'])
```

---

CODE2 :

```
import json
import os
import shutil
path = "filedirectory//samplefolder"
try:  
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:  
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:  
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
source = "filedirectory//images"
dest1 = "filedrectory//tag1"
dest1 = "filedrectory//tag2"
files = os.listdir(source)
with open('filedirectory.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for i, r in enumerate(data):
        if r['label']['tag1'] = 'tag1' 
            shutil.move(f, tag1)
```

The first code displays the label output. 
The second code is what I want to try but not sure if it'll work. Any help?

Comment: Try it and see what happens. If you encounter a problem that you can't solve, then could be the time to ask a question with the accurate description of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see following issues with CODE2:

is: `if r['label']['tag1'] = 'tag1'`
should be: `if r['label']['tag1'] == 'tag1'`

in line: `shutil.move(f, tag1)` you are using `f` and `tag1`, but `tag1` is not defined earlier and `f` is not defined earlier.

I do not know if there are other problems, but if you are fearing it will make mess with your files I suggest you to create function (at begin of CODE2) as follows:

```
def mock_move(a,b):
    print('moving from:',a,'to',b)
```

Then replacing `shutil.move` with `mock_move` and launching your CODE2, thus you will be able to check if it is doing what it should without any movements of your files. After you are sure it works as intended you might replace `mock_move` with `shutil.move` and launch CODE2.